# bluetooth not detect others device hp mini 110-3000

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth can not see any of the device and also when looking for computer bluetooth (visible) is not seen. how do I fix this. I have a lot of time searching on google to find out whether anyone else has the same problem as me.

If you see here I am trying to make sure whether the computer is able to detect my bluetooth by typing `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1fea:0047  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Bluetooth computer it can detect this and I tried to wear the application "system testing" and found this bluetooth device works well whereas this it really does not work well

```
audio/alsa_record_playback_external     skipped 
audio/alsa_record_playback_usb              skipped 
audio/playback_auto                     skipped 
audio/alsa_record_playback_internal     skipped 
benchmarks/disk/hdparm-read_sda             skipped 
benchmarks/disk/hdparm-cache-read_sda       skipped 
bluetooth/detect-output                     PASSED
camera/detect                               skipped 
camera/still                                skipped 
camera/display                              skipped
```

and this problem has persisted from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS until now I was using 12.10 answer to this problem is still not answered yet

When I try to detect where this bluetooth maker I find it is not made ​​from the Cambridge Silicon Radio Bluetooth Dongle, but from AzureWave Technologies, Inc.. I trace it using the MAC address

http://hwaddress.com/?q=% 0974% 3AF0% 3A6D% 3A66% 3A98% 3AAE +

So can I conclude here that it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing following Bluetooth tools Which are in Main Ubuntu Repository.

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-tools bluez-dbg bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev  libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3
```